# How to prove the objective function is jointly concave?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

I have a maximization problem with an objective function of two variables. To prove the concavity of the function, is it sufficient to prove that it is concave with respect to each of the variables? Does the concavity of the function wrt each variable result in its joint concavity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A better approach would be to look at the matrix of second partials (Hessian) and try to check for negative-definiteness.  This is sufficient for concavity (of a smooth multivariate function).

Answer (score 4):

No, Take $f(x,y)=xy$, this function is concave (even Linear!) with respect to each argument, but not Jointly concave. Look at its Hessian !